# menus overlapped on slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Menus are getting hided due to slider overlapping on the menus .unable to see my menus.menu - lessons are not visible. im using jssora22l  which is getting overlapped on my menu 'Lessons' under the tab of Courses. tried with z index 1000 but still im not getting the menus.

code

https://codepen.io/krishnakernel/pen/YNzppX

```
<header class="headerpart">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="logo">
         <a href="#">
         <img class="abc" src="images-Logo.png" alt="krishnamohan" height="50" width="235" />
         </a>
      </div>
      <div class="menu" >
         <nav>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
               <li>
                  <a href="#">Courses</a>
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#">Lesson</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Practicals</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
               <li><a href="url">login</a></li>
               <li><a href="url">Sign up</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
      </div>
   </div>
</header>
<div id="jssor_1" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1300px; height: 500px; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden;">
   <!-- Loading Screen -->
   <div data-u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
      <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: absolute; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
      <div style="position:absolute;display:block;background:url('img/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
   </div>
   <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1300px; height: 500px; overflow: hidden;">
      <div data-p="225.00">
         <img data-u="image" src="img/red.jpg" />
         <div style="position:absolute;top:30px;left:30px;width:480px;height:120px;z-index:0;font-size:50px;color:#ffffff;line-height:60px;">TOUCH SWIPE SLIDER</div>
         <div style="position:absolute;top:300px;left:30px;width:480px;height:120px;z-index:0;font-size:30px;color:#ffffff;line-height:38px;">Build your slider with anything, includes image, content, text, html, photo, picture</div>
         <div data-u="caption" data-t="0" style="position:absolute;top:120px;left:650px;width:470px;height:220px;z-index:0;">
            <img style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:470px;height:220px;z-index:0;" src="img/c-phone-horizontal.png" />
            <div style="position:absolute;top:4px;left:45px;width:379px;height:213px;z-index:0; overflow: hidden;">
               <img data-u="caption" data-t="1" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:379px;height:213px;z-index:0;" src="img/c-slide-1.jpg" />
               <img data-u="caption" data-t="2" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:379px;width:379px;height:213px;z-index:0;" src="img/c-slide-3.jpg" />
            </div>
            <img style="position:absolute;top:4px;left:45px;width:379px;height:213px;z-index:0;" src="img/c-navigator-horizontal.png" />
            <img data-u="caption" data-t="3" style="position:absolute;top:740px;left:1600px;width:257px;height:300px;z-index:0;" src="img/c-finger-pointing.png" />
         </div>
      </div>
      <div data-p="225.00" style="display: none;">
         <img data-u="image" src="img/purple.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div data-p="225.00" data-po="80% 55%" style="display: none;">
         <img data-u="image" src="img/blue.jpg" />
      </div>
      <a data-u="any" href="" style="display:none">Full Width Slider</a>
   </div>
   <!-- Bullet Navigator -->
   <div data-u="navigator" class="jssorb05" style="bottom:16px;right:16px;" data-autocenter="1">
      <!-- bullet navigator item prototype -->
      <div data-u="prototype" style="width:16px;height:16px;"></div>
   </div>
   <!-- Arrow Navigator -->
   <span data-u="arrowleft" class="jssora22l" style="top:0px;left:8px;width:40px;height:58px;" data-autocenter="2"></span>
   <span data-u="arrowright" class="jssora22r" style="top:0px;right:8px;width:40px;height:58px;" data-autocenter="2"></span>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/krishnakernel/pen/YNzppX

screen shot
[image: slider overlapped on menu]

Comment: z-index issue, give the menu a higher z-index. It's always the parents fault.

Comment: could you make your code pen working??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<header class="headerpart" style="z-index:9999;position:relative;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#">

                    <img class="abc" src="images-Logo.png" alt="krishnamohan" height="50" width="235" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="menu" >
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Courses</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Lesson</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">
                                        Practicals
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="url">login</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="url">Sign up</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
<div id="jssor_1" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1300px; height: 500px; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden;">
        <!-- Loading Screen -->
        <div data-u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: absolute; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
            <div style="position:absolute;display:block;background:url('img/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
        </div>
        <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1300px; height: 500px; overflow: hidden;">
            <div data-p="225.00">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/red.jpg" />
                <div style="position:absolute;top:30px;left:30px;width:480px;height:120px;z-index:0;font-size:50px;color:#ffffff;line-height:60px;">TOUCH SWIPE SLIDER</div>
                <div style="position:absolute;top:300px;left:30px;width:480px;height:120px;z-index:0;font-size:30px;color:#ffffff;line-height:38px;">Build your slider with anything, includes image, content, text, html, photo, picture</div>
                <div data-u="caption" data-t="0" style="position:absolute;top:120px;left:650px;width:470px;height:220px;z-index:0;">
                    <img style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:470px;height:220px;z-index:0;" src="img/c-phone-horizontal.png" />
                    <div style="position:absolute;top:4px;left:45px;width:379px;height:213px;z-index:0; overflow: hidden;">
                        <img data-u="caption" data-t="1" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:379px;height:213px;z-index:0;" src="img/c-slide-1.jpg" />
                        <img data-u="caption" data-t="2" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:379px;width:379px;height:213px;z-index:0;" src="img/c-slide-3.jpg" />
                    </div>
                    <img style="position:absolute;top:4px;left:45px;width:379px;height:213px;z-index:0;" src="img/c-navigator-horizontal.png" />
                    <img data-u="caption" data-t="3" style="position:absolute;top:740px;left:1600px;width:257px;height:300px;z-index:0;" src="img/c-finger-pointing.png" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-p="225.00" style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/purple.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div data-p="225.00" data-po="80% 55%" style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/blue.jpg" />
            </div>
            <a data-u="any" href="" style="display:none">Full Width Slider</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Bullet Navigator -->
        <div data-u="navigator" class="jssorb05" style="bottom:16px;right:16px;" data-autocenter="1">
            <!-- bullet navigator item prototype -->
            <div data-u="prototype" style="width:16px;height:16px;"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Arrow Navigator -->
        <span data-u="arrowleft" class="jssora22l" style="top:0px;left:8px;width:40px;height:58px;" data-autocenter="2"></span>
        <span data-u="arrowright" class="jssora22r" style="top:0px;right:8px;width:40px;height:58px;" data-autocenter="2"></span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is likely a z-index issue as many people have pointed out, you should add the following to your css:

```
.headerpart {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

The menu div needs a higher z-index and either `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;` in order for the z-index to work.

```
.headerpart .menu {
   z-index: 2; /* higher z-index for the menu div */
}
```

I also noticed from your codepen that > `.jssorb05 div, .jssorb05 div:hover, .jssorb05 .av` has a value of `overflow: hidden;` which could also be potentially causing the issue. You might need to change that to `overflow: visible;` OR `overflow: auto;`

The codepen provided does not help much as you have not added the styles for your menu HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Set a **z-index** to the header. Don't forget to add a **relative position** to header for z-index work.

```
.headerpart{z-index:9999;position:relative}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your codepen, please give more info.

Answer (score 1):

This is z-index issue give z-index value high to the menubar try the below z-index value to menu class

```
.menu
{
z-index:9999;
position:relative
}
```